# Imageview positioning error

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to set the position of an imageview in a relative layout in landscape mode.

I am using Displaymetrics function to get the screen widt and then calling setleft to set the left position of image view named mStone1.

```
mMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mMetrics);

 mStone1.setLeft(mMetrics.widthPixels-5);
```

But My app is crashing with following error:-

Could not find method android.widget.ImageView.setLeft, referenced from method com.example.Myapp.onCreate

VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11: Landroid/widget/ImageView;.setLeft (I)V

Answer (score 0):

This function is only available for API Level 11 and higher. So, unless you're writing for (and running the app in) Android 3.0, you can't use this function. Maybe try `offsetLeftandRight` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#offsetLeftAndRight(int)

Comment: Be that as it may, View.setLeft()  purpose is not to move a view, but to lay it out (from API docs):
Sets the left position of this view relative to its parent. This method is meant to be called by the layout system and should not generally be called otherwise, because the property may be changed at any time by the layout.

Comment: @jlindenbaum. Thanks for letting me know the cause of the problem.but offsetLeftandRight is also not working for me

Comment: As Dan pointed it, it's really not what you want. Have a look at While-E's post, it's a better programmatic layout approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the `View.Layout(int, int, int, int);` function I believe.

> public void layout (int l, int t, int r, int b)
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> Assign a size and position to a view and all of its descendants
>
> This is the second phase of the layout mechanism. (The first is
>   measuring). In this phase, each parent calls layout on all of its
>   children to position them. This is typically done using the child
>   measurements that were stored in the measure pass().
>
> Derived classes should not override this method. Derived classes with
>   children should override onLayout. In that method, they should call
>   layout on each of their children.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **l  Left position, relative to parent**
>   t  Top position, relative to parent
>   r  Right position, relative to parent
>   b  Bottom position, relative to parent

Comment: this is not working for me.I tried layout function for setting the left position of my imageview relative to the layout.